# My program does not display the correct error message in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this code

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_ord(
   ID_CLIE IN CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID%TYPE, 
   NOMPROD IN products.productname%TYPE,
   QUANTITY IN order_details.quantity%TYPE
)

IS
    CHECKCLI INT; 
    CHECKPROD INT; 
    CHECKQTY INT; 
    ERR_CLI EXCEPTION; 
    ERR_PRODUCT EXCEPTION; 
    ERR_QTY EXCEPTION; 

BEGIN 

    SELECT count(*) INTO CHECKCLI FROM customers WHERE customerid = ID_CLIE; 
    SELECT count(*) INTO  CHECKPROD FROM PRODUCTS WHERE productname = NOMPROD;
    SELECT unitsinstock-quantity INTO CHECKQTY  FROM products WHERE productname = NOMPROD;
    
   
    If CHECKCLI = 0 THEN
        RAISE ERR_CLI; 
    ELSIF  CHECKPROD = 0 THEN
        RAISE ERR_PRODUCT; 
    ELSIF CHECKQTY  < 0 THEN
        RAISE ERR_QTY; 
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO ERRORS');
    END IF; 
    
    
EXCEPTION

    WHEN ERR_CLI THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CLIENT DOESNT EXISTS');
    WHEN ERR_PRODUCT THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT DOESNT EXISTS');
    WHEN ERR_QTY THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT ENOUGH PRODUCTS');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE || ':'|| SQLERRM);

END;
/
```

I want to display different error messages depending on the error, using the RISE function. When I execute `CALL Insert_ord('WILMK','Flotemys', 20);`, it should display the message "PRODUCT DOESNT EXISTS", but it shows me this message instead:

```
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

So, it seems like the if statement is not working. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What is the point of `SQLCODE||':'||SQLERRM`? sqlerrm already includes sqlcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no records fetched from select statements, You will get the error as no data found. You need to use excpetion block to handle the no_data_found exception. Interestingly, When you use count function in select query, If there were no records, you will get the result as 0. So there is no need to use exception block with them. Your updated procedure will look alike -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_ord(
   ID_CLIE IN CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID%TYPE, 
   NOMPROD IN products.productname%TYPE,
   QUANTITY IN order_details.quantity%TYPE
)

IS
    CHECKCLI INT; 
    CHECKPROD INT; 
    CHECKQTY INT; 
    ERR_CLI EXCEPTION; 
    ERR_PRODUCT EXCEPTION; 
    ERR_QTY EXCEPTION; 

BEGIN 
    SELECT count(*)
      INTO CHECKCLI
      FROM customers
     WHERE customerid = ID_CLIE; 

    SELECT count(*)
      INTO CHECKPROD
      FROM PRODUCTS
     WHERE productname = NOMPROD;

    BEGIN
         SELECT unitsinstock-quantity
           INTO CHECKQTY
           FROM products
          WHERE productname = NOMPROD;
    EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                  CHECKQTY := 0;
    END;
   
    If CHECKCLI = 0 THEN
        RAISE ERR_CLI; 
    ELSIF  CHECKPROD = 0 THEN
        RAISE ERR_PRODUCT; 
    ELSIF CHECKQTY  < 0 THEN
        RAISE ERR_QTY; 
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO ERRORS');
    END IF;

EXCEPTION

    WHEN ERR_CLI THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CLIENT DOESNT EXISTS');
    WHEN ERR_PRODUCT THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT DOESNT EXISTS');
    WHEN ERR_QTY THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT ENOUGH PRODUCTS');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE || ':'|| SQLERRM);

END;
/
```